# How to remove specific leading and trailing characters from Euro (€) expression?

Tags: php, regex, substring, preg-replace, currency

I have a string which contains a price inside.

I need to remove the decimal part and currency part of that.

The currency symbol can be removed by PHP using the `str_replace()` function, but the decimal part varies from product to product.

```
<span class="price" id="old-price-3">€&nbsp;200,00 </span>
    <span class="price" id="product-price-3">€&nbsp;80,00</span>
```

I need this like:

```
<span class="price" id="old-price-3">200 </span>
        <span class="price" id="product-price-3">80</span>
```

I tried `str_replace()`:

```
echo str_replace(array(',00','€'),'','<span class="price" id="old-price-3">200 </span>
                <span class="price" id="product-price-3">80</span>');
```

But this only works when there are `00` decimals. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Side note: [I edited](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45905204/2) the question and taken a few words out and fixed some typos/grammar. I hope this does address what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need more than one function call for this.

Match the `€` then zero or more non-digits, then capture one or more digits, then match anything that comes before the end span tag.  Replace with the captured match.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a0b2f674112b37d8bf54d4fe08e6f3e32061ad2d)) ([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/J13t4U/1))

```
$string='<span class="price" id="old-price-3">€&nbsp;200,00 </span>
<span class="price" id="product-price-3">€&nbsp;80,00</span>';

echo preg_replace("/€\D*(\d+)[^<]*/","$1",$string);
```

Output:

```
<span class="price" id="old-price-3">200</span>
<span class="price" id="product-price-3">80</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
/€&nbsp;([0-9]+),([0-9]+)/
```

**Details**:

```
€&nbsp;   start the match with € and a space
([0-9]+)  match any digit 1 or more times
,         match a comma after the first number
([0-9]+)  match any digit 1 or more times after the comma
```

Like this:

```
<?php
$s = '<span class="price" id="old-price-3">€&nbsp;200,00 </span>
<span class="price" id="product-price-3">€&nbsp;80,00</span>';
var_dump(htmlentities(preg_replace("/€&nbsp;([0-9]+),([0-9]+)/", "$1", $s)));
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/6p85S)

Comment: the demo seems working but when i apply to my codes it didn't worked,anyway thank you for the answer